# Why permission of all directory set to full for WSL windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

Not sure if it the case for all or not but since the day I installed the WSL on my windows, I am in my home directory but I could see all the permission is set as `drwxrwxrwx`.

I tried to change the permission using chown but it does not happen, could anyone help on this.

thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

*Short answer:*

Turn on WSL metadata support for Windows drives by:

```
sudo -e /etc/wsl.conf
```

and adding:

```
[automount]
options = "metadata"
```

But please do read below ...

*A few notes:*

- You say you are in your "home directory", but that doesn't appear to be the case.  This is probably just some confusion in terminology, but it also could represent a real problem.  The directory you are showing in your screenshot is the directory for your "Windows *Profile*" (sometimes called "Windows home").  That should *not* be the same as your WSL/Linux "home".

  Inside WSL, try the following commands:

  ```
  echo $HOME
  wslpath $(powershell.exe -c '$env:USERPROFILE')
  ```

  Those *should* be different directories.  If not, then you have probably intentionally changed your WSL/Linux home to be the same as your Windows user profile.  That's not a good idea.  WSL will work better if your WSL user's home directory is on a Linux filesystem.
- Assuming they are different, though, then the next issue is that you mention "changing the permissions" via `chown`.  For clarity, `chown` changes *ownership*.  `chmod` changes permissions.
- Regardless, the answer is pretty much the same for changing permissions or ownership on files on a Windows drive.  Let's start with permissions, since that's specifically what you ask about.

  It's important to realize that WSL only has very limited control over the permissions on a Windows drive.  With the default (no) metadata settings in place for WSL, [the only thing you can do is set a Windows file read-only by removing all write-permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/file-permissions#chmod-file-does-not-have-metadata-default).  In other words:

  ```
   cd $(wslpath $(powershell.exe -c '$env:USERPROFILE' | tr -d '\r')) # Should change to the directory you mention in your question
  touch afile
  ls -l afile
  chmod u-x afile
  ls -l afile # no change
  chmod o-w afile
  ls -l afile # no change
  chmod 644 afile
  ls -l afile # no change
  chmod 444 afile
  ls -l afile # All write permissions are removed, and the file is actually read-only to your Windows user
  sudo chown root afile
  ls -l afile # no change
  chmod 644 afile
  ls -l afile # File appears as 777 again to WSL, and the read-only attribute in Windows is removed
  ```

  After adding the `metadata` option to your `/etc/wsl.conf`, exit WSL, run `wsl --terminate <distro_name>` from PowerShell, and restart WSL.

  WSL will then apply additional metadata to Windows drives which will allow you to set *Linux* permissions on the Windows files.  Changing the Linux permissions will still *not* affect the Windows permissions, other than the read-only scenario mentioned above.

  That said, WSL will then honor these permissions.  For instance:

  ```
  # Assuming same file and directory above
  rm afile
  touch afile
  ls -l afile # File is created with default umask 022:  -rw-r--r--
  chmod u-w afile
  ls -l afile # -r--r--r-- and Windows read-only
  chmod +x afile
  ls -l afile # -r-xr-xr-x, still read-only to Windows
  chmod +w afile
  ls -l afile # -rwxr-xr-x, no longer read-only to Windows
  sudo chown root afile
  ls -l afile # root is owner
  sudo rm afile
  ```

  As noted in the Microsoft permissions doc linked above, though, keep in mind that you can never add a permission that your normal Windows user cannot.  For instance:

  ```
  # From the same user profile directory
  cd ..
  sudo chmod +r Administrator
  # chmod: changing permissions of 'Administrator': Permission denied
  ```

Comment: I wasn't the asker, but it worked for me. Thanks...

Comment: I do not have the `/etc/wsl.conf` file in my local neither the `C:\Users\<UserName>\.wslconfig` on windows, what to do?

Comment: fyi, having windows 10 build 19042

Comment: @IndrajeetGour Running the command `sudo -e /etc/wsl.conf` in WSL will create the file.  It doesn't exist by default.